# 415 unsupported media type : cloud API's

Tags: postman, ibm-cloud, http-status-code-415, ibm-iam

I'm following this IBM cloud doc to generate a IAM token to work with the specific account to which i have access with account id [doc](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-cs_api_install#kube_api)

on postman i'm getting 415 unsupported media error
[image]

[image]
What i could be missing while validating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API for generating an IAM token is documented here in the [IAM Identity Services API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/iam-identity-token-api#create-an-iam-access-token-for-a-user-or-service-i). You are using different (and unsupported) header and body parameters. This could cause the error.

The header should only be `'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`. The body should include the grant type and the API key.